# Django data quality monitoring: best approach to 'construct' queries based on a settings file?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

EDIT 28/04/2021

Have no chances with my question ; )

No one deals with this problem?

---

I want to develop an app for automatic data quality monitoring (DQM) based on different queries:

- missing data
- outliers
- inconsitent data in the same models
- incosistent data between models
- missing form

User should be able to 'customize' its own queries in a structured settings files (in a excel file loaded in a Django model or directly in a Django model with UI interface).
DQM app should read this setting file and run queries with results stored in a model.
User can edit list of query result and make correction in database in order to resolve and improve data quality.

I look for Django package that could already do that but could not find any. So I would appreciate some help in conception.

I have designed the settings files as below :
[image]

I've read about data quality with Pandas bt nothing that cover all data quality queries mentionned above.
Nevertheless, Pandas could be used to read excel settings file using dataframe.
Then, I need to 'construct' query based on the setting file. I thought about 2 options:

- use raw: concatenate SQL orders with data read from dataframe and passed SQL order in raw()
- use Django queryset with unpack dictionnary to provide keyword arguments : qs = mymodel.objects.filter(**kwargs)

Is there a more clean way to achieve data quality?

Comment: how did you do? having the same topics(data quality management), I am interesting with your approach...